# How to handle datatable constraints with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have a data table `ClearingDetail` which has a column `OrdinalNumber` - it's purpose is solely to keep the order that data was entered by the user.

There is also a foreign key `ClearingId`. The `ClearingDetail` table has a unique key which ensures there are no duplicates for the pair (`ClearingId, OrdinalNumber`).

To illustrate the problem, let's assume that we have three records:

```
ClearingDetailId ClearingId OrdinalNumber SomeDetails
1                101        1             Details1
2                101        2             Details2
3                101        3             Details3
```

Now, user deletes the first record, thus after renumbering `OrdinalNumber` the table should contain

```
ClearingDetailId ClearingId OrdinalNumber SomeDetails
2                101        1             Details2
3                101        2             Details3
```

I'm using Entity Framework to handle the database operations. My code looks like this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    RemoveClearingDetailById(1);
    entities.SaveChanges();
    RenumerateClearingDetails(101);
    entities.SaveChanges();
    scope.Complete();
}
```

RemoveClearingDetailById looks like this:

```
void RemoveClearingDetailById(DbContext entities, int id) 
{
    var detailToRemove = entities.ClearingDetails.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ClearingDetailId == id);
    entities.ClearingDetails.Remove(detailToRemove);
}
```

RenumerateClearingDetails looks like this:

```
void RenumerateClearingDetails(DbContext entities, int id)
{
    var i = 0;
    foreach(var detail in entities.ClearingDetails.Where(x=>x.ClearingId == id) 
    {
        detail.OrdinalNumber = ++i;
    }  
}
```

Unfortunately, I get an exception with message:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_UniqueOrdinalNumberWithinClearingId'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ClearingDetail'.
>   The duplicate key value is (101, 1).

Can you tell me how to handle this problem?

Comment: Could you also show your methods RemoveClearingDetailById() and RenumerateClearingDetails()? Might be your changes were not transmitted to the database when deleting, because you are in a single transaction, however I can't be sure without knowing the code.

Comment: I added how body of   RemoveClearingDetailById() and RenumerateClearingDetails() looks like.

Comment: Why renumber at all? Moreover what should happen if you have 2 rows with the same ordinal number but different ClearingId?

Comment: You seem to have done everything right (calling SaveChanges twice, TransactionScope). How many update statements (SQL) do you see?

Comment: @Paolo - nothing, it is completely normal situtation. OrdinalNumbers are for keeping order within the same ClearingId.

Comment: I can see two problems in your solution. First, you are doing both steps within one transaction, so the item originally there is not actually deleted yet. I doubt EF is able to work out that this context state leads to two queries to the database (since the EntityState is Added, however I would assume an DbUpdateConcurrencyException then). Secondly, both your actions take place in the same context. Since Items are not disposed of after SaveChanges() (especially not in the same TransactionScope), you'd have two items with the same given primary key value in your context.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - ok, thank you. Do you have any ideas how to handle this problem? I cannot commit after deleting the first row because if something fails while updating I will end up with unconsistent table state (no OrdinalNumber = 1)

Comment: I guess this is SQL Server? If your purpose is solely to have a sequential number for rows as the user enters them, I would suggest you simply track a timestamp, and then create a view using the row_number() function and a partition over `ClearingId` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: No - OrdinalNumbers are necessary (some other mechanisms use them to identify details and to reflect them on the pdf confirmations and so on, thus from the business logic perspective I have to handle them in the way described above)